# How can I bind keyboard shortcuts for Resharper's "Value Origin" and "Value Destination" commands?

Tags: resharper

I can't seem to find a command for it under Options->Keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign shortcuts to **Resharper.ReShaper_Dfa_ReachingDefinitionsUp** and  **Resharper.ReShaper_Dfa_ReachingDefinitionsDown** commands for 'Value Origin' and 'Value Destination' respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Try typing `reachingdefinition` as a search string in the VS shortcuts window.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could find was using the default keyboard shortcut (for R#2.x/IntelliJ) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for 'Inspect this'.  This pops up a context menu with entries 'Value Origin' and 'Value Destination'.  Not a direct keyboard shortcut, but at least you don't have to take your hands off the keyboard.

Comment: Nope, sorry I didn't mention but I know that already :) I'm looking for a direct shortcut.